# Trying to make a single button on a javascript weather radar be clicked on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make this simple weather radar click the damn play button when the page loads and have tried many things.  The funny thing is, this bookmarklet works on it:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('playerButton play').click();'
```

But I have tried inserting this into the HTML page with so it runs the radar on page load but can't get it to work without a bookmarklet.  BTW, I am not savvy with JS or HTML by any means. Would appreciate help, thank you.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>
      Full Screen Radar
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.wsi.com/1.1/wx.loader.min.js?cid=880798159"> </script>
    <div class="radarContainer" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
    <wx:map scriptId="wxMap" memberId="1167" mapId="0020" templateId="0011" persistOpacity="false" zoomLevel="9" latitude="27.3113" longitude="-82.5957" opacity="0.6" menuItems="0001,1102"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the code that you have provided, where is the play button that you are trying to click?

Comment: If you open that html in the web browser, you will see a weather radar load. I have no idea how it's constructed I didn't make it. I just simply want it to auto-play when loaded.  The source is http://www.wjhg.com/templates/2015_Fullscreen_Radar  I lookat the source code and it loads a bunch of .js scripts to work.  But I'm pretty sure the javascript class of the button is "playerbutton play" because the bookmarklet works.

Comment: it loads this: http://tessera.intellicast.com/en-US/1167/0020/0011/template.js?scriptId=wxMap&memberId=1167&mapId=0020&templateId=0011&culture=en-US&zoomLevel=7&latitude=30.2113&longitude=-85.7957&opacity=0.6&basemap=0014&menuItems=0001,1101&fullScreen=false&enableSidebar=false&enableWeather=false&persistLocation=false&persistAnimation=false&persistOpacity=false&persistZoomLevel=false&persistBasemap=false&persistLayers=false&standalone=false

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!!  It was simple timing issue. All the javascript tricks of waiting the page to finish loading did not work but a 5second timer did:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('playerButton play')[0].click();
  }, 5000);
</script>
```